# How can I add values from other columns and other tables into into this correlated subquery?

Tags: t-sql, correlated-subquery

How can I include worker name and department name column from the other  table into the correlated subquery below? The table should show the worker id and names from workers whose work is not null.

Table Worker:
col:name
Schmitz
Wolfgang

Table: Department
col: dept_name
Counselling
Diagnosis

Table Work:
col:work
project leader
group leader
null
project leader

The correlated subquery below is from the table 'Work'.

```
select worker_id from work AS a  
where not work is null and exists
(select *
from work  as b
where a.worker_id = b.worker_id
and a.work != b.work
)
```

I have tried with nested subqueries and still does not work.

Comment: Probably you want to INNER JOIN worker, but in order to be sure it would be helpful if you post your table definitions, sample data, and desired results (all as text).

Comment: So should your subquery actually be referencing `worker` not `work`?